# Disable a selectable child after initialisation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I cannot see how this can not be working but here's my problem...

I have a series of selectable groups on a page - each one is a row in a table and the div's within the td's are the selectables. Not all td's contain a selectable - this is indicated byt the presence of the 'ignore' class. A lightbox opens and then needs to target several children in one of the selectable groups and disable them from being selectable within their group when the lightbox is then closed.

I have this html (it's a snippet, but accurate):

```
<tr id='row_17' data-booking_row='a room' data-booking_row_id='17'>
    <td class='booking_cell green'>
        <div data-date='2012-10-22' class='room_cell  selectable'>
            <div class='price ignore' style='display:block;'>&pound;5</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class='booking_cell amber ignore'>
        <div data-date='2012-10-23' class='room_cell  ignore'>
            <div class='price ignore' style='display:block;'>&pound;5</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class='booking_cell amber ignore'>
        <div data-date='2012-10-24' class='room_cell  ignore'>
            <div class='price ignore' style='display:block;'>&pound;2</div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The selectable is initiated by this piece of code at the bottom of the page containing the html above:

```
$(function() {
    $('#row_17').selectable({
        filter: 'div:not(.ignore)'
    });
});
```

Then, from the lightbox, I am doing the following to TRY and disable the relevant selectables selected children:

```
parent.$('#row_17 td div[data-date=2012-10-22]').removeClass('selectable');
parent.$('#row_17 td div[data-date=2012-10-22]').addClass('ignore');
parent.$('#row_17 td div[data-date=2012-10-22]').removeClass('green');
parent.$('#row_17 td div[data-date=2012-10-22]').addClass('amber');
parent.$('#row_17 td div[data-date=2012-10-22]').removeClass('ui-selected');
parent.$('#row_17 td div[data-date=2012-10-22]').removeClass('ui-selectee');
```

(The adding of the 'amber' class and removing of the 'green' purely changes the colour)

They are still selectable regardless, the colours do change as they should and the classes have all been added and taken away as they are supposed to if I inspect it but you can still select it.

I have tried adding this at the end of that last block:

```
parent.$('#row_17 td div[data-date=2012-10-22]').selectable('disable');
```

but this errors and tells me "cannot call methods on selectable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'"

Does anyone have any ideas? I really struggle with the lack of context and examples in the new JQuery UI site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with .ready() this waits until the document is ready and the DOM is loaded and can be manipulated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  parent.$('#row_17 td div[data-date=2012-10-22]').selectable('disable');
});
```

Comment: The DOM *is* ready, that code's at the bottom of the page (encountered *after* the browser has assembled the DOM), and is, wrapped in `$(document).ready()` equivalent.

Comment: Yes it's at the bottom so it's definitely initialised. If it helps I've noticed that what I've done, without that last line, prevents you from selecting the children **within** a drag, but you can still click on them to select them. Does that mean anything?!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
parent.$('#row_17').selectable('option','cancel','td div[data-date=2012-10-22]');
```

Comment: Just tried this but it still allows you to click them individually and select them, but they won't select if you drag a box with them inside. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  parent.$('#row_17 td [div*="2012-10-22"').selectable('disable');
});
```